# Are casting times for echoed spells increased for sorcerers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, metamagic

I can clearly see from [Do metamagic feats increase a spell's casting time in Pathfinder?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9935/do-metamagic-feats-increase-a-spells-casting-time-in-pathfinder) that casting times are increased for spontaneous casters when using meta-magic.

[The Echoing Spell metamagic feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/echoing-spell-metamagic/) allows you to recast a spell; my question is if the increased casting time applies to both the original, and the 'echoed' spell for spontaneous casters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you get back an unmodified version of the spell.

> Because the sorcerer or bard has not prepared the spell in a metamagic form in advance, he must apply the metamagic feat on the spot. Therefore, such a character must also take more time to cast a metamagic spell (one enhanced by a metamagic feat) than he does to cast a regular spell.

The increased duration of the initial casting is caused by the need to apply the metamagic. The second casting does not need any modifications to the usual process, so the casting time would not be changed.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes and No**

> Because the sorcerer or bard has not prepared the spell in a metamagic form in advance, he must apply the metamagic feat on the spot. Therefore, such a character must also take more time to cast a metamagic spell (one enhanced by a metamagic feat) than he does to cast a regular spell.

Essentially what increases the casting time is the fact that you are applying a metamagic feat however if you were to apply two metamagic feats then you woul still be dealing with the extended time as the spell that is copied includes the second metamagic that is copied. An example would be if you cast Echoing Twinned Magic Missile then your echoed spell would be Twinned Magic Missile which would have an increased casting time.